# Rails get value from join table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, controller

I have models named `country`, `city` and `province`.

```
Country
has_many: cities

City
has_many :provinces
belongs_to :country

Province
belongs_to :city
```

This model has the same columns `name`, `lat` and `long`

So when I get `params[:name]`, I would like to search on three models in one query with join to find the relevant record.

For instance if it is France it will find it in country etc..

Is this possible?

**EDIT:**

I tried;

```
Country.all.joins(city: :province).where("cities.name = ? or provinces.name = ?", params[:name])
```

But this returns the country. I would like to find if it is country get lat and long, if its city get lat long of the city and if it is province get lat and long of the province.

Comment: What happens if more than one of country, city or province have same name and you are searching for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to find if it is country get lat and long, if its city
>   get lat long of the city and if it is province get lat and long of the
>   province.

I see no other way than checking the existence of records in all three models one at a time like below and getting `lan` and `long` if any of them satisfy the condition.

```
If Country.exists?(name: params[:name])
  Country.where(name: params[:name]).select(:lat, :long)
elsif City.exists?(name: params[:name])
  City.where(name: params[:name]).select(:lat, :long)
elsif Province.exists?(name: params[:name])
  Province.where(name: params[:name]).select(:lat, :long)
else
  #code if none of them matched the condition
end
```

Comment: Allright. I thought kind of same. But was wondering if I can combine and look same column on 3 tables. Thank you